# Put a border on an image in Illustrator or Photoshop or Fireworks

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-fireworks, borders

[image: Like Icon]

I picked up this "like" icon from iconfinder.com.  Originally it was in black.  I adjusted it to orange.  To help the user, I'd like to have it be "hollow" (i.e. just a border - transparent in the middle) before they click it (i.e. before they "like" something) and solid like this after they click it.  I can do the coding to swap image, but I need to create the "hollow" version of this.

I've got photoshop and illustrator and fireworks, but I'm a web developer, so I have no idea how to really use them.  I tried a dozen different things I found online, but nothing is working.  Any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the correct method to do this but I would do the following to achieve the effect

Lower the fill to 0% and add orange stroke from layer styles.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're in Photoshop, correct?  How do you "Effects" and "Stroke" in the layer?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  That works perfect!! Thank you!!